# How can I run a program from bash ignoring its stdout so i can run more programs?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, background-process, process-management

I'm trying to do is create a new process, from within `bash`, like nothing ever happened, except my terminal is on the next line, where that process would normally steal my stdout...

Let's say I want to `apt-get update` right now, but i want to edit some configuration files instead of watching everything download, so I want to run `vi /some/config`. I should be able to do both at once, right?

Just to clarify, because i did a bit of reading before asking, I want this process to survive past the closing of the terminal [if it has not yet come to its end] so i guess that's not a child process, probably not a sub-shell, maybe a fork? Is fork what I mean? How do I fork like this?

Comment: sounds like you want `screen` or `tmux`

Comment: it could work, but i want vi in all its 80*24 glory, cant i just ignore the output of apt-get somehow?

Comment: i dont know how to make this more answerable, especially now that the question has in fact been answered, once by myself and multiple others to produce adequate to exceptional results, i feel like it made more sense when i originally wrote it tho, but ill admit i was never good with words.

Comment: its a rather noobish question anyway, and every answer here is acceptable to varying degrees, so this exchange has served my purposes, if it does not serve yours, feel free to remove it, its moot for me, cheers to all who replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `setsid` command which starts a program in a new session. So you can:

```
setsid apt-get update
```

And, if you want the `apt-get update` to be silent:

```
setsid apt-get update >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The good thing with `setsid` is that the process started this way will continue after the terminal closes.

Comment: i thought i had it with nohup, but actually, i think this is better

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for how to run a process in the background, letting you continue with other work at the same time. This is accomplished by adding an ampersand to the end of a command. For example, milliseconds after running `sleep 5h` you can enter another command while the backgrounded command is doing its thing. To make the process survive the closing of the terminal you'll have to orphan it using `disown`, and to not see standard output (or standard error) you can use [redirects](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiigLm1le3UAhXNFsAKHUkjBysQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmywiki.wooledge.org%2FRedirection&usg=AFQjCNHTKGIIORSs4p-UvNdqBRGuFfkBAw). See [process management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) and [job control](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/JobControl) for great documentation.

Alternatively you can run a command in the foreground and simply start another terminal to do something else. The OS takes care of the rest.

Comment: cheers for the good docs after some reading i found what i needed was nohup

Answer (score 1):

"< /dev/null" is reading stdin from /dev/null - normal redirected input. That immediately returns EOF, i.e. it's reading from an empty file. 
It's a useful idiom for cases where you want to read from STDIN sometimes, but not on this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup apt-get update > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null & vi /some/config
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Overcoming_hanging

technically nohup implies stdin is /dev/null so `< /dev/null` is not needed

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Woah! What is the `< /dev/null` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get update > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

`apt-get update` is the command you want to run.

`> /dev/null` pipes all stdout to /dev/null which, by default, gets rid of it.  You could specify a log file if you wanted to look at the output later.

`2>&1` pipes stderr into stdout.  You could replace &1 with a log file if you wanted to see any errors.

`&` makes the command run in the background.  To see anything running in the background you can try `jobs`.  If you want to tie the process to your shell afterwards you can run `fg`

If you want it to survive past closing the terminal you can `disown` background processes.

Comment: You might want to redirect `apt-get update` to some real fil

Answer (score 0):

In addition of other answers (e.g. background job, [nohup(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nohup.1.html), etc...) you might consider using [`batch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/batch) (from the `at` package that you need to install) with a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), e.g.

```
batch << ENDOFJOB
 apt-get update
 apt-get upgrade
ENDOFJOB
```

<sup>(to run admin commands like `apt-get` you might need to run the `batch` as root)</sup>

Look also into [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) files with [crontab(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html) command, and into [anacron(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/anacron.8.html).

Of course you might want to [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) both *stdout* and *stderr* of your `apt-get` commands (to which you might want to pass `--yes`; read [apt-get(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)), perhaps using something like 
`apt-get update >& /tmp/your-apt-get-update.output`.

Regarding `/dev/null` read [null(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html).